# Iterate through nested array of object in an Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Trying to make a select filter with all the unique coins, but not getting to the end of it correctly.

When looping through data I can get a list of all the coins like this.

```
const uniqueCoins = data.map((item) => {
  item.currencies.map((subItem) => 
  console.log(subItem))
});
```

I also want to use the Set method and spread operator to get just unique values but I'm not sure how to combine all these.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Digitec",
    description: "Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",
    currencies: [
      {coin: "Bitcoin"},
      {coin: "Ethereum"},
      {coin: "XRP"},
    ],
    link: "webseite besuchen",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Galaxus",
    description: "Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",
    currencies: [
      {coin: "Bitcoin"},
      {coin: "Monero"},
      {coin: "XRP"},
    ],
    link: "webseite besuchen",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Brack.ch",
    description: "Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",
    currencies: [
      {coin: "Litecoin"},
      {coin: "Dogecoin"},
      {coin: "XRP"},
    ],
    link: "Onlineshop besuchen",
  },
];
```

Comment: Do you just want an array of the unique coin names like this: `['Bitcoin', 'Monero', 'Dogecoin', ...]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get unique values from array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026895/get-unique-values-from-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by combining all the `coin` values from all the `currencies` arrays using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), add that flattened array to a Set to dedupe the elements, and then spread the Set back out into an array.

```js
const data=[{id:"1",name:"Digitec",description:"Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",currencies:[{coin:"Bitcoin"},{coin:"Ethereum"},{coin:"XRP"}],link:"webseite besuchen"},{id:"2",name:"Galaxus",description:"Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",currencies:[{coin:"Bitcoin"},{coin:"Monero"},{coin:"XRP"}],link:"webseite besuchen"},{id:"3",name:"Brack.ch",description:"Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",currencies:[{coin:"Litecoin"},{coin:"Dogecoin"},{coin:"XRP"}],link:"Onlineshop besuchen"}];

// Get a new array of coins for each object, and then
// flatten all of them into one array
const coins = data.flatMap(obj => {
  return obj.currencies.map(currency => currency.coin);
});

// Create a set from the coins array
const set = new Set(coins);

// `sort and `map` over the array to produce
// an array of HTML for each option
const options = [...set].sort().map(option => {
  return `<option value=${option}>${option}</option>`;
});

// Add those options to a select
const select = `
  <select>
    <option disabled selected>Choose a coin</option>
    <option disabled>----</option>
    ${options.join('')}
  </select>
`

// Add that HTML to a container
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', select);
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for. How do you combine this into a select dropdown menu?

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the array and then remove the duplicates:

```
const uniqueCoins = [...new Set(data.reduce((prev, cur) => prev.concat(cur.currencies.map(cur => cur.coin)), []))]
```

### To break it down :

*Step 1 :* Get all the coins in an array using array.reduce

```
const coins = data.reduce((prev, cur) => prev.concat(cur.currencies.map(cur => cur.coin)), []);
```

*Step 2 :* Remove all the uniques in the array

```
const uniqueCoins = [...new Set(coins)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.flatMap()` method to get the coins sub-arrays and to flatten then array, then use `new Set()` to get unique values.

```js
const data = [{id: "1",name: "Digitec",description: "Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",currencies: [{coin: "Bitcoin"},{coin: "Ethereum"},{coin: "XRP"}],link: "webseite besuchen"},{id: "2",name: "Galaxus",description: "Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",currencies: [{coin: "Bitcoin"},{coin: "Monero"},{coin: "XRP"}],link: "webseite besuchen"},{id: "3",name: "Brack.ch",description: "Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",currencies: [{coin: "Litecoin"},{coin: "Dogecoin"},{coin: "XRP"}],link: "Onlineshop besuchen"}];

const coins = [ ...new Set(
    data.flatMap(({currencies}) => currencies.map(({coin}) => coin))) 
];

console.log( coins );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Digitec",
    description: "Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",
    currencies: [
      {coin: "Bitcoin"},
      {coin: "Ethereum"},
      {coin: "XRP"},
    ],
    link: "webseite besuchen",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Galaxus",
    description: "Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",
    currencies: [
      {coin: "Bitcoin"},
      {coin: "Monero"},
      {coin: "XRP"},
    ],
    link: "webseite besuchen",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Brack.ch",
    description: "Wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",
    currencies: [
      {coin: "Litecoin"},
      {coin: "Dogecoin"},
      {coin: "XRP"},
    ],
    link: "Onlineshop besuchen",
  },
];

const uniqueCoins = [... new Set(data.map(item => item.currencies.map(subItem => subItem.coin))
                        .reduce((arr1, arr2) => arr1.concat(arr2), []))];
console.log(uniqueCoins);
```